# Quadratic timecomplexity: why is the following code calculated this way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-complexity

Could some one please explain why the following code complexity is calculated this way: 1+2+3+4+...+(n-2)+(n-1)+n = O(n^2)

```
def CalculateAveragesTotElementOverzicht(inputlist):
  resultlist = [0]*len(inputlist)
  for i in range(0,len(inputlist)):
      som = 0
      for j in range(0,i+1):
          som += inputlist[j]
      average = som/(i+1)
      resultlist[i] = average
  return resultlist
```

Comment: I would rather say O(n^2) since `sum(1+..+n) = (n+1)*n / 2`

Comment: Your question is not clear, it looks like this function takes a list of numbers and outputs a list of averages of the sums of the numbers until each index. That's what it's doing, you could probably implement it differently but why ?

Comment: `1+2+3+4+...+(n-2)+(n-1)` is indeed `O(n)` but the code is not doing `1+2+3+4+...+(n-2)+(n-1)+n`... further, it's definitely *not* doing Quadratic...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not `O(n)` but O(n<sup>2</sup>). And that's because you have two loops which the outer one iterates from `0` to `n` and the inner one from `0` to the throwaway variables size (`i`) which in each iteration it will generate the following ranges:

```
range(0,0+1) # 1 iteration 
range(0,1+1) # 2 iteration
range(0,2+1) # 3 iteration
   ...
```

Therefore at the end, you'll have 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n iteration which its complexity computes as fllows:

n * (n+1) / 2 = 1/2 n<sup>2</sup> + 1/2n = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Thank you, the complexity is indeed O(n^2), my apologies.